# Multiple words not getting searched , not taking space

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

when i pass string with space in bw the words to the servlet  and run the android aaplication 
error comes like this

```
03-01 09:32:41.110: E/Excepiton(1301): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http//address of server:8088/First/MyServlet?ads_title=test test&city=Pune
```

here `ads_title=test` `test and city = Delhi`

but it works fine when i pass single word string 
like `ads_title=test` 
and `city = Delhi`

but when i run query on sql with both the value that works that means query is fine.

```
String stringURL="http//laddress of server:8088/First/MyServlet" +
String.format("?ads_title=%s&city=%s",editText1.getText(),City);
```

that is where i am passing the values

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding

Comment: If I understand the question, i think you need to use %20 instead of a space.

Comment: URI uri = new URI(string.replace(" ", "%20"));

Comment: strRegUrl=strRegUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20"); best way worked for me tnx Guys happy developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments (not sure why they didn't post as an answer though?) - you want to try encoding your URL - so that the space is handled correctly (%20)

[Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding)

Answer (score 2):

Data sent as a URL must be "encoded" to ensure that all the data passes properly to the server to be interpreted correctly. Fortunately, Java provides a standard class URLEncoder and the encoding specified by the World Wide Web Consortium is "UTF-8 so, use

String finalURL = URLEncoder(stringURL,"UTF-8");

(That way you don't have to know what the encoding is for each special character.)